# excel vba comparing old and new data in rows

Tags: vba

My excel workbook has Sheet1, Sheet2 and Sheet3 sheets.
New data stored in "Sheet1".
Old Data stored in "Sheet2".
UNIQUE ID number is in Column B.

I want to compare row data in "Sheet1" and "Sheet2" and if any differences in a row, those UNIQUE IDs must be stored in "Sheet3"

I get "compile error".
Please help me.

```
Sub comparesheets()
Dim c As String
Dim Dict As Object
Set Dict = New scripting.dictionary
Dim oldData() As Variant, newData() As Variant
oldData = Sheet2.Range("B2").CurrentRegion.Value2
newData = Sheet1.Range("B2").CurrentRegion.Value2
With Dict
For i = 1 To UBound(oldData, 1)
c = getValues(oldData, i, UBound(oldData, 2))
If c <> "" And Not .Exists(c) Then .Add c, Nothing
Next i
For i = 1 To UBound(newData, 1)
c = getValues(newData, i, UBound(newData, 2))
If Not .Exists(c) And c <> blank Then Sheet3.Range("A" & Sheet3.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = c
Next i
End With
Sheet3.Select
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.TextToColumns _
Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True
'Cells.Columns.AutoFit
Range("A1").Select
End Sub
Function getValues(arrayName() As Variant, ByVal r As Integer, c As Integer) As String
For i = 1 To c
oldValues = oldValues & "," & arrayName(r, i)
Next i
getValues = Right(oldValues, Len(oldValues) - 1)
End Function
```

Comment: I could like the question but I don't. Because, what is the compiler error here? Also, I don't believe anyone wants to read your code. Why don't you format it for readability?

Comment: `Set Dict = New scripting.dictionary` - this should be `dim Dict as New scripting.dictionary`

Comment: I changed your tag from vb.net to vba. They are NOT the same language.

Comment: @T.S. Sorry for my inexperience. Replied modification worked. Thank you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because looks like info in comments solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to program this nicely, you would create an object for your record

```vb
public class Record
    public property ColA as integer
    public property ColB as string
    ' MORE properties here 
end class
```

Then you would load "sheet 1" and "sheet 2" into 2 lists

```vb
private _oldList as new List(of Record)
private _newList as new List(of Record)
```

you would create an implementation of `IEqualityComparer(of T)` which will compare items in your 2 lists

```vb
public class RecordComparer
    inherits IEqualityComparer(of Record)

    public function bool Equals(r1 as Record, r2 as Record)

        if r1 is nothing orelse r2 is nothing then
            return false
        else if r1.ColA = r2.ColA AndAlso
                r1.ColB = r2.ColB AndAlso
                . . . . . . .   then '... here you compare all properties that needs to be compared

           return true
        
        else
            return false
    end function

    
end class
```

And then you can simply use LINQ method `Except` to get un-matching subset of records

```vb
dim diffRecords as IEnumerable(of Record)  = _newList.Except(_oldList, new RecordComparer())
```

Now, you can loop through the `diffRecords` records and write them into your "sheet 3". This is much cleaner and nicer that what you're trying to do